# Is there a way to distinguish hooks?

Tags: podio

I create two hooks: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/create-hook-215056

one is 'app' and second is 'app_field', but when I change field I get two notifications:

```
item_id=1329518754&item_revision_id=7&type=item.update&hook_id=16624975
item_id=1329518754&item_revision_id=7&type=item.update&hook_id=16623431
```

Is there a way to distinguish these? I want to react when field is updated and not something updated in the app

Comment: Do you want item field update or app field modified hook?

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha: Yes, I want to distinguish them